# Replace Text label before or after input tag

Tags: javascript, dom

In HTML I have some input tags with labels:

```
<label>Address <input type="text" name="address" /></label>
<label><input type="text" name="surname" /> Surname</label>
```

I want to change labels text with a javascript funcion.
I know it's possible eg. with

```
input_name.parentNode.firstChild.nodeValue = "New label text";
```

Unfortunatly labels are both before and after input. So firstChild as well as lastChild.

I know it's possible to put labels into `<span>` and use getElementById.  But I prefer not.
Maybe it's also possible adding `id` or `for` to the label...  But I prefer not.

How can I easly replace the "first TextNode sibling before or after input"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the `childNodes`, find the first instance of a `TEXT_NODE` and replace the text.

```
var replaceText = function(inputName, newText) {
    var TEXT_NODE = 3, 
        input_name = document.getElementsByName(inputName)[0], 
        nodes = input_name.parentNode.childNodes;

    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].nodeType === TEXT_NODE) {
            nodes[i].nodeValue = newText;
            break;
        }
    }
};

replaceText("address", "Not an Address");
replaceText("surname", "Not a Surname");
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/2gQ9b/)**

Comment: Thank you, very nice.
Why strict equal `nodeType === 3` instead of `== 3`?

Comment: See this answer about `==` and `===` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advice to use a cross-browser framework like JQuery instead of using raw Javascript. Then with Jquery:

```
$('input').bind("keyup", function(event) {
    var textNodes = $(this).parent().contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
    });
    textNodes.each(function() { this.nodeValue = "bla"; });
});
```

Should work! Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hh33v/6/

See http://api.jquery.com/filter/ and http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: Does not work, see http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/sc4g8/.  Plus from the question it appears he wants to replace the `TEXT_NODE` which occurs before or after the input.  By using `.html()` you will destroy the `<input/>` as well.